# Domino tilings of a $2 \times 10$ rectangle with notches

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains, ergodic-theory

You might know that the number of tilings of a $2 \times 1$ rectangle is $F_n$.  For example, the number of tilings here of this $2 \times 10$ rectangle is $F_{10} = 89$:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|                   |
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```

If we had a really big $2 \times n$ rectangle and $n \gg 1$ and tiled that, I could try to draw a $2 \times 4$ box and see what it covers. And we could have a tiling with some defects:

```
 _ _ _ _
|_     _|
 _|_ _|_
```

or (this one does not look possible)

```
 _ _ _ _ 
 _|    _|
|_ _ _|_
```

or

```
 _ _ _ _ 
|     |_
|_ _ _|_
```

Have I missed any?

I am trying to imagine the possible shifts if we move our imaginary $2 \times 4$ rectangle a unit to the right (+1) or to the left (-1) we can end up with one of the boundary conditions above.  So I'm trying to figure out the odds of getting each kind of pattern in box $2 \times 4 \subset 2 \times n$, but also the transition matrix between these patterns under the shift maps $T^{\pm1}: (x,y) \mapsto (x \pm 1, y)$.

Comment: i'm away from my computer, I can address any comments in due time.

Comment: If you colour squares black and white in a chequerboard fashion, you need to remove one square of each colour.